# Laravel floating if greater 85 not working. It show always smaller than 85

Tags: php, laravel, if-statement, laravel-5, conditional-statements

I am learning about backend and Laravel recently.

I am stuck on if function() that using floating type on my project.

```
<td>
  {{$participant->vt_avg}},
  @if($participant->vt_avg > 85)
   x
  @else
   y
  @endif  
</td>
```

It should print vt_avg score, it's "x" if greater than 85 and "y" if smaller than 85.

But it turns out vt_avg,y 
the result shows that all vt_avg is smaller than 85

[image]

Can you please help me? I am stuck with this code.

Comment: "Number y" is a string its not an integer ?

Comment: so, i want to print string x if it vt_avg greater than 85 and string y if it smaller than 85

Comment: can you share your database too I thought its database records

Comment: Also, is it 8.5 or 85?

Comment: There's no visible example of `vt_avg` being greater than 85. Everything in your example is smaller than 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should try this:

```
<td>
  {{$participant->vt_avg}},
  @if($participant->vt_avg > 8.5)
   x
  @else
   y
  @endif  
</td>
```

Comment: it should 8.5. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

How about using floatval() to get the value from string:

(Assuming you want to compare the average with 8.5, not 85)

```
<td>
  {{$participant->vt_avg}},
  @if(floatal($participant->vt_avg) > 8.5)
   x
  @else
   y
  @endif  
</td>
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: i have try it but didnt work. the result is just the same even without using floatval(). because vt_avg is already float

Comment: I see. Do you want to campare the number with `85` or `8.5`? It seems your vt_avg is less than 10. @MichaelRitung

Answer (score 0):

change

```
@if($participant->vt_avg > 85)
```

to

```
@if(floatval($participant->vt_avg > 85))
```

Read about [floatval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php)